# How to copy a license file which is placed with the setup.msi to target directory (setup created with msifactory)

Tags: asp.net, installation, windows-installer

I have created a Setup file i.e. setup.msi , this file contains a website installer

I have a License.xml file that I want to give to my client with the installer (setup.msi).

Before running the setup.msi , client has to make sure that the License.xml file should be in the same directory where setup.msi resist.

I want my setup.msi file to copy the License.xml file to the Destination directory (where website will be installed , this path will be prompted to user for customization)

I am using MSIFactory for creating setup.msi. I am not able to do this. I searched over net but did not get any accurate answer.

Comment: Seems like MSIFactory docs do good job here: http://www.indigorose.com/webhelp/msifact/Program_Reference/File_Operations/Copy_Files.htm

Comment: I tried it but it is not working

Comment: Do you face with any errors? It would be great if you enrich your question with more details

Comment: I am not facing any error, the file is simply not copied

Comment: try generating a verbose log to see what Windows Installer is actually doing

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with MSIfactory, but in installshield what I would do is, call a batch script to do the copy and pass the target directory as a parameter to it. or use the 'XCopyFile' function to do the copying.